# Merge 2 dataframes according to length of list (using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, merge

I have one dataframe `df1` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dic1 = {'A':['a','b','c','d','e'],
        'B':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,150,np.nan],
        'C':['x','y','z','v','w']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
```

I then have a second dataframe `df2`:

```
dic2 = {'X':['c','e','b'],
        'Y':[2,4,1],
        'Z':[[188],[160,200],[784]]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
```

where column 'X' corresponds to some of the value found in 'A'; column 'Y' corresponds to the indexes of the values of the items of 'A' present in 'X'.

My goal is the following:

- Step 1: Select only the rows having 1 element in the list in column 'Z'
- Step 2: Substitute the values of the selected lists in the column 'B' according to the indexes contained in 'Y'.

I was able to achieve my goal with the following lines of code:

```
# Step 1
df2 = df2.loc[df2['Z'].str.len() == 1] 

# Step 2
for idx,row in df2.iterrows():
    df1.set_value(row['Y'],'B',row['Z'][0])
```

Can you suggest me a smarter or more efficient way to achieve my goal maybe using some function of pandas? I would like to avoid using for loops if possible.

The output should look like this:

```
# Before            # After
   A      B  C         A      B  C
0  a    NaN  x      0  a    NaN  x
1  b    NaN  y ---> 1  b  784.0  y
2  c    NaN  z ---> 2  c  188.0  z
3  d  150.0  v      3  d  150.0  v
4  e    NaN  w      4  e    NaN  w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) for remove `lists` from column `Z`:

```
df2 = df2[df2['Z'].str.len() == 1] 
df2.Z = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2['Z'].values.tolist(), index=df2.index)
print (df2)
   X  Y    Z
0  c  2  188
2  b  1  784
```

And then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN` to values of `df1`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('A')
df1.B = df1['B'].combine_first(df2.set_index('X')['Z'])
#df1.B = df1['B'].fillna(df2.set_index('X')['Z'])
print (df1.reset_index())
   A      B  C
0  a    NaN  x
1  b  784.0  y
2  c  188.0  z
3  d  150.0  v
4  e    NaN  w
```